# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'el' of undefined

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

fullcalendar.js code

```
if (segs.length) {
  for (i = 0; i < segs.length; i++) {
    this.beforeFgSegHtml(segs[i]);
    html += this.fgSegHtml(segs[i], disableResizing);
  }

  $(html).each(function(i, node) {
    var seg = segs[i];
    var el = $(node);
    if (hasEventRenderHandlers) {
      el = _this.filterEventRenderEl(seg.footprint, el);
    }
    if (el) {
      el.data('fc-seg', seg);
      seg.el = el;
      renderedSegs.push(seg);
    }
  });
}
```

i tried                 `if(el && seg != typeof 'undefined')` in js file.But still error is occur..what can i do?

Comment: It should be `typeof seg != 'undefined'`

Comment: Why don't you just do everything in the `for` loop instead of concatenating all the HTML?

Comment: thanx Barmar..i tried the same ,but it doesn't work..

Comment: I can't find methods like `fgSegHtml()` at https://fullcalendar.io/docs